# What could be down sides of using mysql json field instead of many nullable fields on a table in laravel 5

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

As you know, mysql 5.7 provides json fields. What could be down sides of using a data json fields instead of having many nullable fields on a table? Let's say i'm working on a products table which has length, width, height, thickness, margin, ... all in nullable property. I think is better to use json data column instead of using all these nullable columns. But i don't know what could be down sides!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what do you use the field for. Let's say if you need to do lots of join/search on that value then it's recommended to be stored within a column instead of the json field (for performance purposes, json field cannot be indexed). However if it's just used for storing information, then json is fine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm not using indexing for these columns, but i don't know if it's right or not. Maybe using where clause on json is worse than having many null fields!

Comment: that's essentially what I meant, if you don't need to run search/join on it then json is fine.